# Как в bot.send_message выдать данные перебора в виде одного сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу чтобы бот одним сообщением через \n выдал мне каждого автора или каждую цитату в одном сообщении, не знаю как это сделать

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def func(x,message):      #функция перебора
    l=[]
    for x in x:
        l.append(x.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,l)
    print(l) 

response = requests.get('https://quotes.toscrape.com/')
soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find_all('span',class_='text')    #цитаты
autors = soup.find_all('small',class_='author')  #авторы цитат



@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'цитаты':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цитаты:')     #выписываю цитаты
        func(quotes,message)        
    if message.text == 'авторы':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Авторы:')     #выписываю авторов
        func(autors,message)
```

Исходный вариант,который отдельными сообщениями выдает авторов:

```
def func(x,message):      #функция перебора
    for x in x:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, заменил функцию отбора

```
def func(x):    # функция отбора
    msg=''
    l=[]
    for x in x:
        l.append(x.text)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        msg+=l[i]+'\n'
    print(msg)
```